# Integral in termsof supremum

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am facing difficulty to prove the following fact:
If $w$ is a locally integrable positive function in $\Omega$, then 
$$
\sup_{B(x,R)}\lvert v\rvert=\lim_{p\to\infty}\lVert v\rVert_{L^p(B(x,R),w))},
$$
where $B(x,R)\subset \Omega$ and $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, and $\lVert v\rVert_{L^p(B(x,R),w))}$ is defined to be
$$
\left(\int_{B(x,R)}\lvert v\rvert^pw(x)\,dx\right)^{1/p}.
$$
For $w=1$, I know this is true. But for non-constant $w$, even for $A_p$ weights does the same hold true? I have sen this fact is applied in the paper attached in the link: see page 15 or 16.
http://imar.ro/journals/Mathematical_Reports/Pdfs/2017/3/3.pdf

Comment: If $w=0$ this cannot be true.

Comment: For $A_p$ weights $w$ of course $w$ is nonzero (a.e.), so the same proof works.

Comment: Can you kindly have a look at the foolwing question in the link : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996709/estimate-on-average-with-weight